# Background image changing when it's in landscape mode in MIT App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I uploaded two image for background of my app in MIT App Inventor 2. Once I set a background image for portrait orientation it's ok, but when it's come to landscape same image is showing. I want show different images when device change it's orientation. I have tried in some ways with the screen's logic blocks in the block section. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `screen.ScreenOrientationChanged` event handler. Add an `If, Then, Else` block and test if the `screen.Width` is larger than `screen.Height`. If so, set your landscape image, if not, set your Portrait image.